# return observable that is deferred

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ng-bootstrap

I keep having this issue and I don't think my approach is best and would appreciate some help.

I have a function return an observable that won't be available until some time (user clicks modal button, http calls finish, etc.). Let's say I want to display a confirmation modal and either proceed or return from the function depending on what the user selects. (note: the modal returns a promise)

```
doWork = () => {
  openConfirm().subsribe(res => {
    if (!res) { return };   // return from function if user selects 'No'
    
    // else proceed
  });
}
```

here is where I think I am returning the observable wrong using from

```
openConfirm = (): Observable<any> => {

  // ng bootstrap modal asking "Would you like to proceed" with a yes or no button 
  let modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmModalComponent, {});


 return from(modalRef.result.then(res => {
        return true;  // Yes button
      }, () => { 
        return false;  // No button
      }));
  }
}
```

I want the observable to wait until the user selects yes or no on the modal before returning. as it is in my case. But is there a cleaner way? if I remove the from() operator and return of(true) or of(false) I get an error that I can't subscribe to undefined.

Comment: Is [`defer()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/defer) what you're looking for?

Comment: @martin not quite, sometimes I subscribe to observables and the data isn't ready to be returned right away, like in this example the modal click), and I either get subscribe errors or have to do use this ugly from() code or of() if its not a promise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain but try this using the `from` operator like you have [1](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from).

```
doWork = () => {
  openConfirm().subsribe(res => {
    // promise was a success - Yes clicked
  }, err => { // error callback of subscribe
    // promise was a failure - No clicked
  });
}
.....
openConfirm = (): Observable<any> => {

  // ng bootstrap modal asking "Would you like to proceed" with a yes or no button 
  let modalRef = this.modalService.open(ConfirmModalComponent, {});


   return from(modalRef.result)
  }
}
```

See if you can take advantage of just returning from(Promise) and subscribing to this promise and seeing if the observable funnels properly to the success callback and error callbacks.

Comment: Thank you, it works and is much cleaner. I didn't realize a rejected promise hits the error block of the observable.